# Sinon stub not replacing function in test

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, sinon

I've looked through similar questions and still cannot figure out why my sinon stub isn't working. The test is still calling the original function.

userFlow.js

```
function authorization() {
  const options = {
    name: 'buzz',
    state: 'bazz'
  }

  return options
}

const credentials = authorization()

async function main() {
  return credentials.name;
}


main();

module.exports = {
  authorization,
  main
};
```

test.userFlow.js

```
const userFlow = require('../userFlow.js');

describe('userFlow()', function() {
    it('should authorize', async function() {
        options = {
            name: 'foo',
            state: 'bar',
        }; 
        sinon.stub(userFlow, 'authorization').returns(options);
        const output = userFlow.main()
        assert(output === foo)
    })
})
```

I end up with output === buzz.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is order of operations. When you do this...

```
const userFlow = require('../userFlow.js');
```

It runs this...

```
const credentials = authorization()
```

So your sinon override doesn't matter. What I would try is something like this...

```
async function main(authorization) {
  return authorization().name;
}
...
const output = userFlow.main(userFlow.authorization)
```